# Writing to a txt file by xp_cmdshell

Tags: windows, sql-server-2005, shell

I m trying to write query result to txt file. Here is my code:

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select * from Leasings" queryout "DHCPLog.txt" -c -t,-T MyServerIP'
```

But the result is :

[image]

And there is no row in DHCPLog.txt. Do you have any suggestion about this?

KR,

Çağın

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing a space after the comma and that you need to use the -S flag to specify the server name because -T is not enough. A command similar to the following works for me here:

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select * from Leasings" queryout "DHCPLog.txt" -c -t, -T -S MyServerIP'
```